# How to implement a double tap gesture on tab bar item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbar

I am developing an music app for a client and he need an app like the following image.

However when user press the  middle button once He need to show a full screen player and if user pressed the button twice he needs to show a mini audio player.

Is there a way to do it ? if so how ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With  `TabBarControllerDelegate` you can know if the selected tab is the current tab, for know this you can use - `(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

In this method you can `return NO` to the TabBar not switch the `viewController` (if you use a navigationController the tab bar do `popViewContorller` when you do duble tap) and you can show your audio player.

This do what you want?